# .net c# validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

Good afternoon,

I have a simple form that using C# server side validation. When using a radio button or dropdownlist with `AutoPostBack`, I have to call `Page.Validate()` within the code behind method.  When I do this, it does not run the Javascript on the page that overrides the default functions of the C# validation.

How can I get the javascript - `ValidatorUpdateDisplay` function to run when I call the `Page.Validate()` call in the autopostback method?

Thanks in advance!

Rob

Javascript:

```
// Form Validation: Change TextBox CSS for outline color
ValidatorUpdateDisplay = function (val) {

    var ctl = $('#' + val.controltovalidate);
    var eCount = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {        
        var v = Page_Validators[i];

        if (v.controltovalidate == val.controltovalidate) {                      
            if (!v.isvalid) {
                eCount++;
                ctl.addClass('validationError');
                $('td.question:eq(' + i + ')').addClass('someClass');                           
            }        
        }
    }

    if (eCount > 0) {
        ctl.addClass('validationError');
    } 
    else {
        ctl.removeClass('validationError');
        // $('td.question:eq(' + i + ')').removeClass('someClass');
    }

    if (typeof (val.display) == "string") {
        if (val.display == "None") {
            return;
        }
        else if (val.display == "Dynamic") {
            val.style.display = val.isvalid ? "none" : "inline";
            return;
        }
    }

    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Mac") > -1 &&
        navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") > -1) {
        val.style.display = "inline";
    }

    val.style.visibility = val.isvalid ? "hidden" : "visible";
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure of the specific problem, but here's a link that may have some insight in how to override the ValidatorUpdateDisplay function:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14181/Enhancing-the-presentation-of-standard-validator-o

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code based on `RegisterStartupScript`

```
 var javaScript = 
  "<script language=JavaScript>
   ValidatorUpdateDisplay(); 
   </script>";

 RegisterStartupScript("Key_ClickScript", javaScript);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//C# validation for number only- 

if (!(e.KeyChar >= '0' && e.KeyChar <= '9' || e.KeyChar == 8))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                MessageBox.Show("This textbox accepts only Numbers");
            }  

//C# validation for characters only-

if (!char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) && !(e.KeyChar == 8) && !(e.KeyChar == 32))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                MessageBox.Show("This textbox accepts only alphabetical characters");
            }
```

Comment: I don't think this is applicable for asp.net